# ActivePython uninstall

Tags: python

I've uninstalled ActivePython yet all my python projects still save with the ActivePython logo rather than Idle, and when I try to open them it says "These types of files cannot be opened on your PC". I have removed python and everything to do with python several times but it has done nothing. Is there anything I can do to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the uninstall program for ActivePython has not removed the *file association* and *file type* between `*.py` files and the ActivePython program.

You could try and use the [`assoc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb490865.aspx) and [`ftype`](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb490912.aspx) programs to correct this.